# Cmake ROS failure: Mac OSX deployment target mismatch

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, ros

I'm trying to compile [LSD-SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) using ROS in Mac OSX Yosemite (v10.10.4). ROS Jade is set and the source code has been checked out.

However `rosmake` seems to fail.

Here is the output:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['lsd_slam']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /Users/apple/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20151109-185908
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['lsd_slam'] to:
['lsd_slam_core', 'lsd_slam_viewer'] 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]
```

.
.
. 
   *Lots of build messages*
.
.
.

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> lsd_slam_viewer [ make ]                               
[ rosmake ] All 18 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/apple/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:76 (message):
    CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:

     ""

    is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
    CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
    empty.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.3.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
    CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/Users/apple/ros_catkin_ws/package_dir/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_viewer/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package lsd_slam_viewer written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/apple/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20151109-185908/lsd_slam_viewer/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< lsd_slam_viewer [FAIL] [ 0.09 seconds ]                
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package lsd_slam_viewer. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 42 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /Users/apple/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20151109-185908
```

What lies at the heart of this problem is this little line here:

```
CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.6' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT: ""
```

I went through this message list:

https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-November/052649.html

and this:

https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=15f5764e

but couldn't solve my problem from this.

I tried updating the SDK root using:

```
export SDKROOT=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

I also tried commenting out the system root target from public.cmake, as suggested by this:
http://answers.ros.org/question/50561/cmake_osx_deployment_target-and-cmake_osx_sysroot/

But no joy.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it is a bug in ROS. Write a bug report or have a look in their current master. Maybe the fix is already there and can be pack-ported to your version.

Comment: Ah... the catch is, these folks do not provide any support for Mac. They have tested it on Ubuntu alone and do not say anything about Mac. Now that I'm trying to hack my way into building this for Mac, this particular error here seems to stem from some cmake config issue. That is my best guess.

Comment: You have to track down, where the variable is set and pinpoint the line, where it gets a value on Ubuntu but is empty on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.
please try it.
commenting one line in ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake as shown below:

`if(APPLE)
 #SET(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.6" CACHE STRING "Deployment target for OSX" FORCE)
 endif(APPLE)`

Comment: Put the relevant info into the post.

Comment: I've mentioned this in the question already, I tried commenting that line ... didn't work.